# Во время анимации ломается overflow:hidden

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Добрый день уважаемые. Возникла такая проблема при использовании css анимации по событию :hover у соседних элементов с тем же классом ломается свойство  overflow: hidden; Не могу понять почему, и как исправить? 
[image: нормальное отображение]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для тех кто знает в чём причина, или хочет удивить проблему в действии
https://github.com/BlackStar1991/gbo
Запускать фаилы index_offers.html и styles/main.scss (Строки 449 467)

```css
.box-offers {
  width: 100%;
}

.box-gbo__link:hover .box-gbo__offer-image {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: transform 1.5s;
}

.box-gbo__offer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 4% 0;
  border-radius: 20px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

  background-color: $colorbgTextBloc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.box-gbo__offer-image {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1.5s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mainWrappen">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="box-offers">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a class="box-gbo__link" href="#">
                                    <div class="box-gbo__offer">
                                        <img class="box-gbo__offer-image" src="../img/offers/daewoo-l__1.png" alt="gbo">
                                        <p class="box-gbo__offer-text">econom</p>

                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="box-gbo__link" href="#">
                                    <div class="box-gbo__offer">
                                        <img class="box-gbo__offer-image" src="../img/offers/audi_s6_sedan_2012___2.png"
                                             alt="gbo">
                                        <p class="box-gbo__offer-text">premium</p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a class="box-gbo__link" href="#">
                                    <div class="box-gbo__offer">
                                        <img class="box-gbo__offer-image"
                                             src="../img/offers/audi-rs-q3-tfsi-mtm-122__3.png" alt="gbo">
                                        <p class="box-gbo__offer-text">standart</p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="box-gbo__link" href="#">
                                    <div class="box-gbo__offer">
                                        <img class="box-gbo__offer-image" src="../img/offers/porsh__4.png" alt="gbo">

                                        <p class="box-gbo__offer-text">Lux</p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box-offers__gboInformation">

                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте стили сюда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно `border-radius: 20px;` к `.box-gbo__offer-image`